# In VS2010 with C#, How to get and save an image from URL that sent binary not static image?

Tags: c#, image, binary

There is an url like www.demoimage.com/?imageNo=34, and that url shows an image on the browser. 
What i need is to save this image to hdd as .jpg , i tried this sample and works 
http://www.co-scripts.com/url--den-resimleri-binary-olarak-alip-kaydetme
But some urls returns 0 bytes of reply tı my httprequest.
I change the request header, timeout, userAgent, buffer etc. But failed again.
Why some urls returned 0 bytes while it renders as image on standart browsers like ie 8, chrome, mozilla?
PS: I need to save as file, not to save to any sqllike etc. databases
Thank you
Caglar

Comment: Does it throw any exceptions? Can you look and see the headers, and see what http status code is returned for the urls that give 0?

Comment: Do you have a link to the actual image so I can see the headers being sent? I'm almost certain it has to do with a request header as the host should be passing back a Content-type telling the browser that it's an image not standard textual content.

Comment: The original link has ip check control that cause refused for unregistered ips. That application will get the News Agency broadcast for their customers. Broadcast inclueds news and images. Our machine has accepted (registered to the NewsAgencys servers) customer ip, that is static.

Comment: @Paul there is no exception. Only zero byte and an zero byte length image (.jpg). I am at home now, tomorrow i will write the returned http answer from the server.

Comment: Also the original link returns the real image when we use a standart browser.

Comment: If you're using FireFox, I recommend using the `TamperData` ad-on and seeing which headers are being sent/received. Then you can compare those up against what you're sending/receiving.

Answer (score 1):

In short you will have to use WebRequest and WebResponse classes to get the image stream.

Comment: The OP linked to the sample he used. That sample already uses `WebRequest` and `WebResponse`.

Comment: At the end of many tries, we decided server controls something behind we could understand. 
Now we are going to try browser control to render url as image and then try to save image as jpg to local.

Comment: We got the images as jpg from loaded page of web browser control via DOM. Thank you.